# JMeter - Java HTTP Client implementation show 0 connect time and sent bytes

Tags: jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x

I wonder about the differences I found regarding HTTP Client implementation,

There's options to choose HTTPClient 4 or Java

But for a simple case (www.google.com) Java implementation **always** show 0 in connect time and sent bytes Sampler results:

```
Connect Time: 0
Sent bytes:0
```

While HTTPClient 4 return different values each time as:

```
Connect Time: 100
Sent bytes:117
```

Request body is the same

```
GET http://www.google.com/

GET data:


[no cookies]
```

But Request Header differ while HttpClient sends also `Host` and `User-Agent`

```
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_25)
```

Is there a valid reason for these differences?

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

<strike>Just to make it more confusing, when choosing empty implementation (should use default) the connect time is **always** 0 but Sent bytes is **never** 0</strike>

<strike>Connect Time: 0
    Sent bytes:117</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java and HttpClient are 2 different implementations that can be used by HTTP Request.

The java one is less rich than hc4 and for example it does not implement :

- sent bytes metric computation
- connection time metric
- kerberos authentication

There are also other features missing in Java implementation.

When you select empty, the value in property «jmeter.httpsampler »  is used, by default it’s hc4.

Comment: Thank you for answering, just why I select empty the Connect Time is 0

Comment: Are you sure about it ? isn’t it possible that it was really 0 ? Try reproducing, if you do report  a bug. Thanks